# DataGridView AccessibleName

Tags: c#, winforms, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a `DataGridView` on a Winforms form and, as usual, space is limited. The column titles are therefore often abbreviated ("Qty.", "No." etc.). My **screenreader** (`JAWS`) handles the `DataGridView` like a table and reads the column header as I navigate through the "cells" (i.e. the controls in the grid). Ideally, I would like to get the screenreader to use an accessible name for the header, so it would read "quantity" instead of "queue tea why".

I can't find an `AccessibleName` property for the column or the column header. Does anyone know where it is lurking, or is it simply not available?

Comment: @Vland AFAIK all screenreaders use the AccessibleName property to announce the names of normal controls like text boxes. With a checkbox, for example, they announce the checkbox text if there is no AccessibleName defined or the AccessibleName if it is defined. In this case, JAWS is (correctly) seeing the grid as a table (the same as an HTML or Word table) and announcing the column header in each control. This header is in turn taken from the field names in the underlying dataset. It is not a showstopper, but would be nice to have if I could override it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about JAWS but if you you have a space issue with your DGV columns why don't you set the column header `DefaultCellStyle` > `WrapMode` property to true, So that if you use more than one word in any column header text it can be wrapped. So you might be able to use meaningful column names instead of abbreviations.

Comment: Yes, but in a good few cases, the column width is only a couple of characters wide, especially if it contains only a checkbox or a (max. 4-digit) number.

Comment: Ok, I think this is something you need to experiment with JAWS, Check its support for abbreviated text, Check if you can set it to read Tooltip text in case the control's text length is few characters.

Comment: @BlindFury If you have horizontal space issue another workaround would be to use horizontal scroll bar so that you could use meaningful column header text.

Comment: Yep, you can get JAWS (and other screenreaders) to expand abbreviations, and many of the SAPI voices do this anyway, but as a translator, I usually need it to read exactly what is on the page, warts and all. I guess sacrificing visual appearance for screen-readability is the way forward. It is a custom application for me and my secretary only. She will have to put up with a little ugliness!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how JAWS works, if you just need a property called `AccessibleName` you can create a new DataGridView Column class inheriting from `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`

```
public class AccessibleDataGridViewTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    public string AccessibleName { get; set; }
}
```

and adding them to your `DataGridView`. You can then set the property with your desired text in the designer or in your code.

Comment: I'd like to try this out of interest, but I would have to read the dataset into the grid manually, would I not? I still need the grid bound to the DS.